# How to determine columns dynamically for the SELECT query in MySQL with CASE statement. OR: How to replace columns dynamically in the SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I have to make some SQL query.
I'll only put here tables and results I need - I am sure this is the best way for a clear explanation (at the bottom of the question I provided SQL queries for database filling).

---

- short description:

TASK: After `full join` concatenation I receive a result where (for example) `tableA.point` column (that is used in the SELECT statement) in some cells returns `NULL`. In these cases, I need to change `tableA.point` column to the `tableB.point` (from the joined table).

So, tables:

(Columns `point` + `date` are composite key.)

- outcome_o:

[image]

- income_o:

[image]

- The result I need an example (we can see - I need a concatenated table with both `out` and `inc` columns in rows)

[image]

---

My attempt:

```sql
SELECT outcome_o.point,
       outcome_o.date, 
       inc, 
       out
FROM income_o 
     FULL JOIN outcome_o ON income_o.point = outcome_o.point AND income_o.date = outcome_o.date
```

The result is the same as I need, except `NULL` in different `point` and `date` columns:

[image]

I tried to avoid this with `CASE` statement:

```sql
SELECT 
CASE outcome_o.point
  WHEN NULL 
    THEN income_o.point
    ELSE outcome_o.point
END as point,
....
```

But this not works as I imagined (all cells became NULL in `point` column).

Could anyone help me with this solution? I know there is I have to use `JOIN`, `CASE` (case-mandatory) and possibly `UNION` commands.
Thanks

---

Tables creation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE income(
    point INT,
    date VARCHAR(60),
    inc FLOAT
)

CREATE TABLE outcome(
    point INT,
    date VARCHAR(60),
    ou_t FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO income VALUES
    (1, '2001-03-22',   15000.0000),
    (1, '2001-03-23',   15000.0000),
    (1, '2001-03-24',   3400.0000),
    (1, '2001-04-13',   5000.0000),
    (1, '2001-05-11',   4500.0000),
    (2, '2001-03-22',   10000.0000),
    (2, '2001-03-24',   1500.0000),
    (3, '2001-09-13',   11500.0000),
    (3, '2001-10-02',   18000.0000);

INSERT INTO outcome VALUES
    (1, '2001-03-14 00:00:00.000',  15348.0000),
    (1, '2001-03-24 00:00:00.000',  3663.0000),
    (1, '2001-03-26 00:00:00.000',  1221.0000),
    (1, '2001-03-28 00:00:00.000',  2075.0000),
    (1, '2001-03-29 00:00:00.000',  2004.0000),
    (1, '2001-04-11 00:00:00.000',  3195.0400),
    (1, '2001-04-13 00:00:00.000',  4490.0000),
    (1, '2001-04-27 00:00:00.000',  3110.0000),
    (1, '2001-05-11 00:00:00.000',  2530.0000),
    (2, '2001-03-22 00:00:00.000',  1440.0000),
    (2, '2001-03-29 00:00:00.000',  7848.0000),
    (2, '2001-04-02 00:00:00.000',  2040.0000),
    (3, '2001-09-13 00:00:00.000',  1500.0000),
    (3, '2001-09-14 00:00:00.000',  2300.0000),
    (3, '2002-09-16 00:00:00.000',  2150.0000);
```

Comment: You need a `LEFT JOIN` with running date as reference table. What is your MySQL version?

Comment: @FanoFN Hi, mySQL version - 8.0.30

Comment: Can you post the `income_o` and `outcome_o` data in text format? I want to copy and paste for testing purpose.

Comment: @FanoFN few minutes, I"ll post INSERT queries for table creations. Thanks

Comment: @FanoFN question updated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to create a date range reference table. To do that, we can use Common Table Expression (cte):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT Min(mndate) mindt, MAX(mxdate) maxdt 
    FROM (SELECT MIN(date) AS mndate, MAX(date) AS mxdate 
            FROM outcome 
        UNION
          SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) 
            FROM income) v 
   UNION
  SELECT mindt + INTERVAL 1 DAY, maxdt
   FROM cte 
   WHERE mindt + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= maxdt)
SELECT mindt
   FROM cte
```

Here I'm trying to generate the dynamic date range based on the minimum & maximum date value from both of your tables. This is particularly useful when you don't want to keep on changing the date range but if you don't mind, you can just generate them simply like so:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT '2001-03-14 00:00:00' dt 
   UNION
  SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   FROM cte 
   WHERE dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2002-09-16')
SELECT dt
   FROM cte
```

From here, I'll do a `CROSS JOIN` to get the distinct `point` value from both tables:

```
...
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT point FROM outcome 
                 UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT point FROM income) p
```

Now we have a reference table with all the `point` and date range. Let's wrap those in another cte.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT Min(mndate) mindt, MAX(mxdate) maxdt 
    FROM (SELECT MIN(date) AS mndate, MAX(date) AS mxdate 
            FROM outcome 
        UNION
          SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) 
            FROM income) v 
   UNION
  SELECT mindt + INTERVAL 1 DAY, maxdt
   FROM cte 
   WHERE mindt + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= maxdt),
  cte2 AS (
SELECT point, mindt
   FROM cte 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT point FROM outcome 
                 UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT point FROM income) p)
SELECT * 
  FROM cte2;
```

Next step is taking your current query attempt and `LEFT JOIN` it to the reference table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT Min(mndate) mindt, MAX(mxdate) maxdt 
    FROM (SELECT MIN(date) AS mndate, MAX(date) AS mxdate 
            FROM outcome 
        UNION
          SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date) 
            FROM income) v 
   UNION
  SELECT mindt + INTERVAL 1 DAY, maxdt
   FROM cte 
   WHERE mindt + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= maxdt),
  cte2 AS (
SELECT point, CAST(mindt AS DATE) AS rdate
   FROM cte 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT point FROM outcome 
                 UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT point FROM income) p)
SELECT * 
  FROM cte2
  LEFT JOIN outcome 
     ON cte2.point=outcome.point
    AND cte2.rdate=outcome.date
  LEFT JOIN income 
    ON cte2.point=income.point
    AND cte2.rdate=income.date
/*added conditions*/
WHERE cte2.point=1
AND COALESCE(outcome.date, income.date) IS NOT NULL
/*****/
 ORDER BY cte2.rdate;
```

I noticed that your `date` column is using `VARCHAR()` datatype instead of `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Which is why my initial test return only one result. However, I do notice that if I compare `YYYY-MM-DD` format against your table `date` value, it returns other results, which is why I did `CAST(mindt AS DATE) AS rdate` in `cte2`. I do recommend that you change the `date` column to MySQL standard date format though.

You probably find the query a bit too long but if you have a table where you store dates or as we call it calendar table, the query will be much shorter, perhaps like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM calendar
  LEFT JOIN outcome 
     ON calendar.point=outcome.point
    AND calendar.rdate=outcome.date
  LEFT JOIN income 
    ON calendar.point=income.point
    AND calendar.rdate=income.date
/*added conditions*/
WHERE calendar.point=1
AND COALESCE(outcome.date, income.date) IS NOT NULL
/*****/
 ORDER BY calendar.rdate;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4AeSA9PX)

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was using the wrong syntax for the solution. So, as I found out, dynamically column selection is accessible in the SELECT query:

- correct `CASE` statement:

```sql
(
CASE 
WHEN outcome_o.point IS NULL
THEN income_o.point
ELSE outcome_o.point
END
) as point,
```

In this case query selects joined table column in the case the main table column is `NULL`.

- Full query (returns result exactly I need):

```sql
SELECT 
(
CASE 
WHEN outcome_o.point IS NULL
THEN income_o.point
ELSE outcome_o.point
END
) as point,
(
CASE
WHEN outcome_o.date IS NULL
THEN income_o.date
ELSE outcome_o.date
END
) as date, 
       inc, 
       out
FROM income_o 
     FULL JOIN outcome_o ON income_o.point = outcome_o.point AND income_o.date = outcome_o.date
```